# Global attributes on Visualforce tab (to Lightning Component)

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, global-variables

I built a Lightning Component I am using on a record page by sending `global` attributes via the appBuilder:

```
<aura:attribute name="attr1" type="Integer" access="global" />
<aura:attribute name="attr2" type="Integer" access="global" />
```

**This component works fine.**

I am also using **this** component in a *Visualforce page* (rendered in a Visualforce tab) as this:

```
  <script>
    $Lightning.use('c:MyLightningComponent', function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:MyLightningComponent",
        {},
        "lightning",
        function(cmp) {});
    });
  </script>
```

I would like to fill the `attr1` and `attr2` from there as this:

```
  <script>
    $Lightning.use('c:MyLightningComponent', function() {
      $Lightning.createComponent("c:MyLightningComponent",
        { attr1: 2, attr2: 3 },
        "lightning",
        function(cmp) {});
    });
  </script>
```

**WHERE** I need `3` and `2` **to be global variable (as they are on a Lightning Component)**.

How can I set "global" parameters for a Visualforce page/tab I can transfer to Lightning Component ?

Comment: How can I specify URL params on a Visualforce Tab ?

Comment: Ah, I missed the tab thing, getter;setter is the only way I could think of.